# Android Keyboard do not open on focus in Edittext

Tags: android

There are lot of questions regarding android keyboard not opening ,when there is a focus on edittext.
And there are many ways also to open keyboard forcefully.However usually keyboard opens automatically on request focus. But in some cases it do not opens even there is a focus in edittext.

What usually happens behind that keyboard do not appears automatically as it usually does ?

Comment: can you please explain the last sentence (the question itself)? do you mean you want to know how to show the keyboard forcefully ?

Comment: @android developer i know how to show keyboard forcefully(Got help from stack overflow),here i am interested in knowing why some times keyboard do not pop up automatically

Comment: well i consider this a bug, as on some devices and android versions it works fine, and on some it doesn't. you could try the next post, but i'm not sure if it works fine on all cases : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17142034/878126 . i've tested it only on a few devices and android versions.

Comment: @android developer thanks

Comment: did it work well for you? maybe i should have written an answer instead of a comment... if i will, and it worked for you, would you mark it as the correct one?

Comment: @android developer No i did not used your answer i used some thing else .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32320/discussion-between-suresh-bora-and-android-developer)

Answer (score 0):

For automatic keyboard, use the following

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

also this can help in manifest file :

```
               <activity
                   android:name="com.example.activities.MyActivity"
                   android:configChanges="keyboard"
                 >
               </activity>
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the solution , however i am interested in knowing why keyboard do not comes automatically sometimes ,not how to get the keyboard automatically

Comment: Oh..is it the first clickable thing on your screen ?? If not, then, maybe some other clicable item is taking the focus . Otherwise, its quite strange ! do let me know if you find the reason.  Thanks !