# Click anywhere in EditText to show keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to make Hello World notepad app, and currently I have to click right on the cursor in my EditText to bring up the soft keyboard. I would like to be able to click anywhere in the EditText to show the keyboard.

Here is my EditText declaration in my layout:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"  >
</EditText>
```

**EDIT:**

I am using the Galaxy Nexus emulator, and here is what I get:

[image: screen]

I have to click in the area above the blue marker to get the keyboard.

Comment: Sounds like something weird with your device. EditText should show the keyboard no matter where you click inside of it

Comment: Checkout [Keyboard not shown when i click on edittextview in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977773/keyboard-not-shown-when-i-click-on-edittextview-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:inputType="text"  >
</EditText>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. With "wrap_content" the EditText view is quite tiny at the beginning (as you can see yourself in your screenshot). layout_width="match_parent" makes it stretch across the screen (if parent view does so). Setting layout_height to match_parent might be a bit over-exaggerated but surely works.

Answer (score 2):

Use below code for showing softkeyboard when your edittext get focus for example

```
youredittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() 
{

@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

if(hasFocus)                                
{

InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInputFromInputMethod(youeedittext.getWindowToken(), 0);

}   



}



});
```

This will show Soft keyboard each time your edittext gewt focus ...if not work use same code in OnClick event for your edittext...

or

Check this in AVD Manager [image]

Hope it helps..