# The focus when several EditText in an Activity?

Tags: android

There is an EditText in MainActivity,and There are two EditTexts in PopupWindow,I want to input text in EditText in PopupWindow,but the softkeyboard can not display and so I can not input text.How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a common issue on some phones/android versions.
See here for some possible solutions: [EditText in PopupWindow not showing keyboard even if setFocusable(true)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21793908/edittext-in-popupwindow-not-showing-keyboard-even-if-setfocusabletrue)

Comment: Thank you,the issue had been resolved,the function PopupWindow.requestFocus() must be called and the function PopupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable() must be called too.Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
editTextName.requestFocus();
```