# EditText in popup window: keyboard isn't shown

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I've created a layout for a survey as a popup window, but somehow keyboard isn't shown when a focus is true, even after a tap to the edittext...

In other activities, all EditTexts work correctly.

Recently, I've changed app Theme to AppCompat to implement Material components. I am not sure it can impact, but no ideas from my side, why it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#66ccff"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageSurveyClose"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingTop="40dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"          
        android:gravity="center"    
        android:text="Question"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="22dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageSurveyClose"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/close"
        android:background="@null" />

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Send" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio0"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="v1"                
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:textSize="22dp"
                android:buttonTint="#ffffff"  
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"             
                />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"               
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"                
                android:text="v2"
                android:buttonTint="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="22dp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radio2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:buttonTint="#ffffff"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="v3"                               
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:textSize="22dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                 />
        </RadioGroup>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioGroup2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup2"
            android:layout_marginTop="47dp"                        
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did it only break after you changed the theme?

Comment: @Brian, I've changed theme firstly to use Material, so I don't know...

Comment: @DimaKozhevin, I don't want to hide it, it doesn't show... So the issue is to show it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105354/how-to-show-soft-keyboard-when-edittext-is-focused

Comment: @DimaKozhevin didn't help, I understand that I have an issue with setting or manifest, but can't get what the matter

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21793908/edittext-in-popupwindow-not-showing-keyboard-even-if-setfocusabletrue - the right answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing the **<requestFocus />** element in the EditText and see whether the keyboard appears. Afterwards you can request the focus programmatically inside the activity.

Comment: it doesn't help