# Fragment detail Android

Tags: android

How can you add a simple edittext field to the detail fragment? (for the master/detail layout app). If I add one, I cannot type in it and the keyboard doesn't show. Are there further settings I need to do? I have not found a proper example.

This is all I did. Just wanted to check if it works.

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/example"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="@string/example"
android:inputType="text" />
```

Comment: Post some code on what you have tried so far so that stackoverflow community can help you easily

Comment: you facing problem in edit text, means when you  click on edittext field it is not showing keyboard right

Comment: @Allu Yes but on the list fragment or on another page/app it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, it worked for me.

```
EditText etHorseName = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.horseName);
etHorseName.clearFocus();
```

in onCreate() or where you want

Comment: if you didn't get then see this url also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977773/keyboard-not-shown-when-i-click-on-edittextview-in-android

Comment: The application stops if I do that.