# Android EditText keyboard not shown in Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I added `EditText` in `Fragment`, but my `EditText` is not showing keyboard even if I click on `EditText`.

Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/setting_nickname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="8"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:hint="Samantha"
        android:textColorHint="@color/nav_selected"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textColor="@color/nav_selected"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/setting_country"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="8"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:hint="Samantha"
        android:textColorHint="@color/nav_selected"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textColor="@color/nav_selected"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" >
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

I try to get listener of `EditText`

```
final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
edit_nickname.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        imm.showSoftInput(edit_nickname, 0);

        //edit_nickname.requestFocus();  --> fail
        //imm.showSoftInput(edit_nickname, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);  --> fail
        //imm.showSoftInput(edit_nickname, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);  --> fail
    }
});
```

And this code is fail to...

```
final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

Also, I try to add `LinearLayout` to have `focusableInTouchMode` and `focusable`, but failed.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@color/black_transparent"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:focusable="true">
    <EditText .../>
    <EditText .../>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

If I use `<requestFocus />` than keyboard is shown up but It applies to only one of `EditText`. How can I do? And why not the keyboard is shown?

Comment: You should not require any additional code to show the keypad on edit text touch, can you post the class file?

Comment: @Skynet I also think there is no need for any action T.T.. Also, I did not do anything in my class file.

Comment: @Skynet Just only set `View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.setting, container, false);` and `return rootView;` in `onCreateView`

Comment: I for one suspect that something else is taking the focus of your click.

Comment: Did you got solution I am having same problem

Comment: I had a similar problem and have discovered a fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56097616/1617737

Answer (score 1):

Try using this, it works for me

```
EditText myEd= (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.myEd);
myEd.requestFocus(); 
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
mgr.showSoftInput(myEd, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try execute the following code in a separate thread or handler.

```
 editText.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    if(imm != null)
                    imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                }
            },1000);
```

Comment: Thanks! But this code occurs only when create a fragment. I want to shown up keyboard when focus on `EditText`

Comment: I just updated my answer, try giving some delay of time. In the above code i have given 1000 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest that You called your Code :

```
InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            keyboard.showSoftInput(edit_nickname, 0);
```

By Implementing the EditText Touch listner method and You got the Result as follows :

```
edit_nickname.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            keyboard.showSoftInput(edit_nickname, 0);


            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried in the same way as on your answer but it's not work to me.. T.T

Comment: Are you getting any Errors ?

Comment: Please try to add the above code and remove if you have added any other touch event on the EditText as i was already done that.

Comment: But I already above my code. I only apply your code but it's not work.. T.T

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
private InputMethodManager mInputMethodManager;

EditText mRecordFileNameET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.recorder_recordFileName_et);
mRecordFileNameET.setOnKeyListener(this);

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.recorder_recordFileName_tv:
        mRecordFileNameET.requestFocus();
        showSoftKeyboard(true);
        break;
    }

}

//this method is used to show and hide soft keyboard
private void showSoftKeyboard(boolean showkeyboard) {
    if (showkeyboard) {
        mInputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        mInputMethodManager.showSoftInput(mRecordFileNameET, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    } else {
        mInputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        mInputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mRecordFileNameET.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

}
```

Hope this helps...