# EditText doen't open keyboard in popup

Tags: android, android-layout

This layout is used for popup window to change name of a textview.But the edittext doesnt show keyboard even on clicking the edittext. I'm using it  in a fragment. fragment has a namefield which is meant to be changed on clicking OK in this popup.

**This is the xml file for popup window.**

```
 <RelativeLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fff">


  <LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/name_status_btns"
    >

    <Button

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:text="CANCEL"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:id="@+id/cancel_change_name"/>


  <TextView

        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#b1b0b0"/>


   <Button

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="OK"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:id="@+id/ok_change_name"
        />


    </LinearLayout>


<TextView

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#b1b0b0"
    android:layout_above="@id/name_status_btns"
    android:id="@+id/name_status_horizontal_liner"/>


  <RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/name_status_edit_field">


    <EditText

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:hint="write your name here"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:id="@+id/change_name"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>


   </RelativeLayout>



   <TextView

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/mainColor"
    android:layout_below="@id/name_status_edit_field"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"

    />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

**This is the java file for above xml.**

```
public class Name_Status extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

EditText name_change;
RelativeLayout name_status_edit_field;
String name;
Button cancel_name_change , ok_name_change;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.name_status);
     DisplayMetrics dm=new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    int width=dm.widthPixels;
    int height=dm.heightPixels;

    getWindow().setLayout((int)(width*.8),(int)(height*.3));
    name_change=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.change_name);
    name_status_edit_field=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.name_status_edit_field);
    name=name_change.getText().toString();
    cancel_name_change=(Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel_change_name);
    ok_name_change=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ok_change_name);
    ok_name_change.setOnClickListener(this);
    name_change.setOnClickListener(this);
   name_status_edit_field.clearFocus();
    name_change.setFocusable(true);
    //name_change.update();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
           if(v.getId()==R.id.ok_change_name)
           {FragActivity1 obj=new FragActivity1();
    obj.changeName(name);
    Intent intent=new Intent();
    intent.setClass(Name_Status.this , MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);}
    if(v.getId()==R.id.change_name)
    {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(name_change.getApplicationWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is your `EditText` has a `0dp` width and a `layout_weight` attribute in a `RelativeLayout`, which does not make any sense.

Either make the parent of the `EditText` a `LinearLayout` *or* remove the `layout_weight` attribute from the `EditText` and give it a proper width:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/change_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="write your name here"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>
```

The following code is completely unnecessary, you should just remove it from `onClick()`:

```
if(v.getId()==R.id.change_name)
{
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.
        INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(name_change.getApplicationWindowToken(),
        InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following for EditText

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(final View v, final boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus && editText.isEnabled() && editText.isFocusable())
            editText.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context
                            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                }
            });
    }
});
```

For more details refer [Keyboard not shown when i click on edittextview in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977773/keyboard-not-shown-when-i-click-on-edittextview-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

`EditText` is not suppose to have `0dp` width and `layout_weight` inside a `RelativeLayout`. Weight works inside `LinearLayout`. So change your `EditText` to below:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="write your name here"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:id="@+id/change_name"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>
```

And change your `OnClick` to because `EditText` will take care of click by itself:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
if(v.getId()==R.id.ok_change_name){
    FragActivity1 obj=new FragActivity1();
    obj.changeName(name);
    Intent intent=new Intent();
    intent.setClass(Name_Status.this , MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

And finally remove the below line from your `OnCreate()` method:

```
name_change.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Because `EditText` will open keyboard by itself when clicked.