# No Edittext field in my application is running. Keyboard is not turned on

Tags: android, android-edittext

The keyboard is never turned on when the Edittext field is touched.
I do not know the cause of this problem. However, I can not write any edittext field in my application.
My Gradle;

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "dotdotdot"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}}dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
implementation 'com.github.filippudak.progresspieview:library:1.0.+'
implementation 'com.github.rahatarmanahmed:circularprogressview:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
implementation 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.0.2'
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
implementation 'com.github.aakira:expandable-layout:1.4.2@aar'
implementation 'com.github.mirrajabi:search-dialog:1.1'
implementation 'com.roomorama:caldroid:3.0.1'
implementation 'net.igenius:customcheckbox:1.3'
implementation 'com.evrencoskun.library:tableview:0.8.6'
implementation 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.10.0'
implementation 'com.github.piasy:GlideImageLoader:1.4.6'
implementation 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1'
implementation 'org.sufficientlysecure:html-textview:3.5'
implementation 'com.github.irshulx:laser-native-editor:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
implementation 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:3.1.1'
implementation 'com.github.firdausmaulan:GlideSlider:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.6.0'
implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'
implementation 'com.alespero:expandable-cardview:0.6'
```

My Sample EditText Area :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:text="Notlar"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/notes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/details_top_margin_large"
        android:hint="No Data.."
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have two activity. LoginActivity and MainActivity. There are also many fragments.

Edittexts are working well in LoginActivity (Username and Password) but no edittext is working in MainActivity.

I did a major update of the SDK yesterday. I do not know if it can be related to it because I did not make much changes in the codes.

> I solved the problem. This took a day. I could not figure out why, but I moved the project to a new project. And edittext fields are now working.

Comment: Did you test it in real device too?

Comment: Yes, on 3 different devices. The problem continues

Comment: Can you post the full code of MainActivity xml

Comment: https://pastebin.aquilenet.fr/?7160a6a560ded099#vuc2M9/K0eOwT4eKVMUg1wTjDkbG5Dz4uauFxBzghFk=    This link contain my xml file.

Comment: this link might be help https://stackoverflow.com/a/7743066/5995648

Answer (score 0):

Your EditText works just fine in my phone, both virtual and real device.

However,

The problem may be caused if you do not have all the SDK Tools installed. Please install everything listed in SDK Tools section.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll try.

Comment: Yes but can't solve my problem. I moved all codes to new project and the problem has been solved.

Comment: Unfortunately I could not find the source of the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

In case the other solutions haven‘t already worked, you may try to make the `EditText` focusable:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```